# compile multiple files c++, doesnt name a type

Tags: c++, compilation

I have a problem compiling multiple files with codeblocks. My problem is that the compiler doesnt recognize the class types that i created. I get the error doesnt name a type. I have add at all header files the #ifndef, #deffine. My files are:

`forum.h`

```
#include <list>
#include "thread.h"
class Forum
{
private:
    std::list<Forum*> forums;
    std::list<Thread*> themata;
}
```

`thread.h`

```
#include <list>
#include "forum.h"
#include "post.h"
class Thread
{
private:
    Forum* forum; //gia tin allagi thesis otan ginei stick
    int id;
    std::list <Post*> lista;
}
```

`post.h`

```
#include "system.h"
class Post
{
private:
    System* system;
}
```

What can i do for that ?

Comment: are you putting `;` after the class declaration?

Comment: Yeah exactly, likely you forgot a `;` after the class definition. If you actually have it, then post the **full** error message, not just your interpretation. Thank you!

Comment: i put ; at the end of the class, that's not the problem

Comment: @user2936672 also take care of the circular dependence, as Cihan T. pointed out

Comment: Yep, I too see a dependency between `forum.h` and `thread.h`, because one requires the other and vice-versa. Also, fix your code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular header dependency. Use forward declarations to break it. For example, in `forum.h`, forward declare the `Thread` class instead of including its header like this:

```
#include <list>

class Thread;

class Forum
{
private:
    std::list<Forum*> forums;
    std::list<Thread*> themata;
};
```

Include the header in `forum.cpp`.

Comment: Because your "thread.h" depends on "forum.h", which in turn depends on "thread.h". This is called a circular dependency which will prevent the compiler from resolving them.

Comment: @user2936672 because `include` literally pastes the content of the file, so now imagine what happens, even if you protect the header with `#ifndef/endif`. Basically, to declare `Forum`, you use `Thread`, and to declare `Thread`, you use `Forum` (which MUST use `Thread`) and so on. The idea is to use the so called *incomplete types*, which allows you to use pointers and references to them via a so called *forward declaration*, without specifying the full definition (basically a compiler can use a pointer without knowing the full definition of what it points to).